# Display records on load page using jquery ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to load data when page is loaded but if i try doing that then delete function doesn't work and whenever I insert the effect should be seen in table without refreshing page Please check my code what changes to be done in this

index.php

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#Submit").click(function(e) {

        var name = $('#name').val();        
        var message=$('#message').val();
        if($(":text").val().length==0)                      
        {
            $(":text").after('<span class="error">Field cannot be empty</span>');   
            $('#name').addClass('error');   
            $('#message').addClass('error');                
            return;
        }
        else{
            $('#name').removeClass('error');
            $('#message').removeClass('error');
            //$('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error');                          
            $('#propspectDiv').html('Submitting your Request.<img src="ajax.gif" />');  
            $.ajax({
                    url : 'data.php',                   
                    data:{
                        "name" : name,
                        "message" : message             
                    },
                    success : function(data){
                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#propspectDiv').html('Your Name is added to our records'); 
                            $('#data').css("display","block");  
                            $('#data').html(data);              
                        }, 2000);
                    },
                    complete:function(){
                    $('#myform').each(function(){
                    this.reset();   
                });
           }
                });
        }

        });

    $("a").click(function() {
       $.post('delete.php',{ id: $(this).attr("id")});
    }); 
    });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myform">
    <div id="wrapper">
     Name :    <input type="text" id="name"  />
                   </br>
     Message : <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
                   </br>

        <input type="button" value="Submit"  id="Submit" />
        <div id="propspectDiv"></div>
        <table id="data" border="1" style="display:none;"></table>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

data.php

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
include('connection.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO login (username,message) VALUES ('$name','$message')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

    $sqlnew = 'Select * from login order by id ASC';
    $res = mysql_query($sqlnew);
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>SrNo.</td>';
    echo '<td>Name:</td>';
    echo '<td>Message:</td>';
    echo '<td>Delete</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['message'].'</td>';
        echo"<td id=td1>
          <a href=delete.php?id=".$row['id']."&type=Delete>Delete</a></td>"; 
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

  if(isset($_REQUEST["id"]))
  {
  $cmd=mysql_query("delete from login where id=" .$_REQUEST["id"] .";");
   header("location: index.php");
  }


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your grabbing the ID attribute of the link, but not setting it...

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $.post('delete.php',{ id: $(this).attr("id")});
});
```

There is no ID attribute on your existing delete link:

```
 <a href=delete.php?id=".$row['id']."&type=Delete>Delete</a></td>";
```

Also - you probably don't need to have the link href pointing to delete.php as its irrelevant when the jquery click event does all the work.

Also, because you are inserting the html (including the delete method) via jquery you may need to use the "on" event

I'm doing this off the cuff so the code may have some minor bugs but I believe this is the path you want to take...

Revised it might look like this:

**JQUERY**

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $.post('delete.php',{ id: $(this).attr("id")});
  return false;
});
```

**LINK**

```
echo"<td id=td1>
    <a id='".$row['id']."' href='#'>Delete</a>"; 
echo '</tr>';
```

couple things to note...

1 - above i'm not actually VERIFYING the record was deleted before I remove the appropriate table row - you may want to implement something to check this

2 - an alternative to removing the table row would be to just update the table in general by repulling the data and outputting it - if you know what i mean

Comment: Thanks it helped me to delete records but after delete the html table is not displaying

Comment: After you delete the records, inside the on("click", function(e) { method you will have to call to update your table via ajax, like you do  when you output the HTML using this: $('#data').html(data); - do you know what i mean?

Comment: you actually might be able to just remove the table row that was deleted - check out my updated code above - specifically $(this).parent().remove(); - this may get you what you need

Comment: I don't know how to do it can u please help I m just learning jquery ajax It wolud be very helpful

Comment: if i understand correctly - you want to update the html table after you delete the record - correct? if so - check how I updated the sample above as it may solve your problem in updating to reflect the newly deleted record.

Comment: Thanks I tried but still its not working it deletes record but html table vanishes

Comment: just curious - is the page posting back when you click the delete link?

Comment: Check the updated jquery code, hopefully that will prevent the postback

Comment: There is no reason there should be a postback on that link the more I think about it

Comment: That doesn't look like your original code, why have the fadeout?

Comment: is there any problem the way I am displaying data on submit thats why it vanishes?

Comment: Thank You for your help my work is still not completed but this answer helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome - sorry I was away - how about you start up another question - because you kind of had a few questions in 1 here - start up another one with all the details and code - it will make it easier for me to review and test